# Sending files automatic from Azure server to a third party

Tags: backup, azure

Im new here, hope I'm in the right place.
We have a few Azure servers to provide a hosting environment for our webbased application, third partys access a website we provide and they work in our webbased application and also store data (files) in it.

Recently we got a question from a client of ours if we could provide weekly back-ups of the databases and the files he has uploaded to our server(s). To make sure that if something happens to us, he still has his data. Fair question, the problem is, we don't really have an answer for it.

We already make back-ups of the databases daily. So all we are basicly looking for is something that sends the database back-up file and uploaded documents to the third party automaticly, lets say each sunday at 23:00. To be clear, the documents are NOT in the database. It can be as simple as "Send this folder each sunday to this emailaddress". Maybe with use of Wetransfer, we have a professional account there.

Who can help us?

Comment: Azure server, do you mean Azure VM(Iaas) or webapp(Paas)?

Answer (score 0):

If your just looking got something to transfer the data automatically there are a a couple of options:

1. [Azure Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro) - This would require you to write the PowerShell scripts to undertake the transfer, but the automation platform would provide a way for you to run them on a regular basis and to control credentials etc.
2. [Azure Data Factory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) - This allows you to build worksflows (throuhg JSON or using a graphical workflow builder) that connect different data sources. So for example you could transfer your files and backups from blob storage to your clients FTP site.

Answer (score 0):

If your servers are **Linux** based I would recommend setting up a CRON job on each server to send the desired data to your third-party application. The CRON job can be scheduled to execute at any desired time and run a script. If they are **Windows** based you can use Task Scheduler to kick off a script at a scheduled time.

Linux: https://aka.ms/cron

Windows: https://aka.ms/task_scheduler

Depending on the third-party application you are using you will either need to write a script to make an HTTP PUT request to the backup location or upload via FTP.

You can also use the Azure Function service to kick off your scripts at a scheduled time.

https://aka.ms/azure_functions